# how to link html video using laravel path?

Tags: html, video

I want to ask how to properly link an MP4 video in laravel... my problem is that it doesn't play the video

```
        <video width="250" controls>
            <source src= 'img/products/video-main.mp4' type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>
```

Comment: so is this a laravel problem, or you don't know how to set up the `<video>` tag and/or point it to the proper url?

Comment: Do you get the error msg? Thats a browser issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your solution :)

```
<source src= '{{ url('img/products/video-main.mp4') }} ' type="video/mp4">
```